# [react]history.push changes url, but not rendering page

Tags: reactjs

`history.push` in SearchInput.js changes url, but it does not re-render the page :(
I read some posts handling this issue, but all does not work.

`SearchInput.js` component is called at `header`.

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import AppContext from '../contexts/AppContext';
import Login from './Login';
import Main from './Main';
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

const history = createBrowserHistory();
const App = () => {

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{}}>
      <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={Login} exact/>
          <Route path="/contents" component={Main}/>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </AppContext.Provider>
  )
};

export default App;
```

main.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import _ from "lodash";

import Header from './Share/Header';
import Footer from './Share/Footer';
import Alert from './Share/Alert';
import AlertContext from '../contexts/AlertContext';
import ShareDataContext from '../contexts/ShareDataContext';
import Search from './Search/Search';
import Targeting from './Targeting/Targeting';
import ModelHit from './ModelHit/ModelHit';
import {KEY_NAME} from '../consts/keyName';

const Main = (props) => {
  const [alertState, setAlertState] = useState({
    eventType: '',
    eventMessage: '',
    eventCount: 0,
  });

  return (
    <AlertContext.Provider value={{ alertState, setAlertState }}>
        <Header quarterRawData={quarterRawData}/>
        <Alert />
        <main className="blue-grey lighten-5">
          <Route path="/contents/search" component={Search} exact />
          <Route path="/contents/targeting" component={Targeting}  exact />
          <Route path="/contents/model-hit-list" component={ModelHit}  exact />
        </main>
        <Footer />
    </AlertContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

SearchInput.js -> where call history.push

```
/* eslint-disable no-use-before-define */
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';
import {KEY_NAME} from '../../consts/keyName'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const SearchInput = (props) => {
    // Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
    const {options} = props;
    const history = useHistory();

    const searchHandler = (e, value) => {
        if (value) {
            history.push({
                pathname: '/contents/search',
                state: {
                    [KEY_NAME.SHARE_CODE]: value[KEY_NAME.SHARE_CODE],
                },
            })
        }
    }

    return (
        <Autocomplete
            id="combo-box-demo"
            options={options}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option['target']}
            style={{ width: 400 }}
            onChange={searchHandler}
            renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Search" variant="outlined"/>}
        />
    );
}

export default SearchInput;
```

Comment: This link might help you: https://reactforyou.com/history-push-is-only-changing-the-url-not-rendering-component-react-fix/ -- I am looking for a fix for a similar problem but have not managed to find one yet... but your code looks a litte similar to the blog post linked.

Comment: Thank you Nij, I solved the issue.

Comment: the reason was I inserted history.push commend on the component which does not be included in Router instance. I tried history push in the header component :( so I solved that issue using withRouter